Como comparar dos campos con equals cuando uno tiene minusculas y el otro mayusculas
Cordial saludo. En la actualidad estamos diseñando un aplicativo para control de llantas de vehículos. En dicho aplicativo, buscamos identificar si las llantas ya fueron ingresadas a la base de datos, para marcarla como "Insertada" o "Pendiente" si no esta en dicha tabla. Luego de poner a funcionar el codigo, encontramos que habian muchas llantas que ya habian sido ingresadas a la tabla, pero que a pesar de ello, aun continuaban apareciendo como "Pendiente".
Este es el código.
[HttpGet("/Llantas/Salidas/Registros/Validados", Name = "GetLlantasSalidasRegistrosValidados")]
    public List<TemLlantasSalidasRegistros> GetLlantasSalidasRegistrosValidados(int Anho, int Mes, 
        string? Obra, string? Almacen) 
    {
        try
        {
            var t = GetLlantasSalidasAgregarObras(Anho, Mes);
            var q = from a in t
                    where
                        (
                            Obra == null
                            ||
                            Obra == ""
                            ||
                            Obra == a.Obra
                        )
                        &&
                        (
                            Almacen == null
                            ||
                            Almacen == ""
                            ||
                            Almacen == a.nom_bodega
                        )
                    // 2024-01-23: join con la tabla obtenida en GetLlantasHistoricosRegistros
                    join b1 in GetLlantasHistoricosRegistros(Anho, Mes) on new TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros
                    {
                        Fecha = a.fecha,
                        Equipo = a.equipo,
                        Salida = a.numero,
                        Bodega = a.bodega,
                        Cantidad = a.cantidad
                    }
                    equals new TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros
                    {
                        Fecha = b1.Fecha,
                        Equipo = b1.Equipo,
                        Salida = b1.Salida,
                        Bodega = b1.Bodega,
                        Cantidad = b1.Cantidad
                    }
                    into GrupoB
                    // 2024-01-23: esto lo hago para que que sean LEFT JOIN.
                    from b in GrupoB.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    orderby
                        a.Obra,
                        a.equipo,
                        a.fecha
                    select new TemLlantasSalidasRegistros
                    {
                        Registro = a.Registro,
                        equipo = a.equipo,
                        bodega = a.bodega,
                        nom_bodega = a.nom_bodega,
                        cod_familia = a.cod_familia,
                        familia = a.familia,
                        fecha = a.fecha,
                        codigo = a.codigo,
                        descripcion = a.descripcion,
                        tipo_salida = a.tipo_salida,
                        tipo = a.tipo,
                        numero = a.numero,
                        cantidad = a.cantidad,
                        costo = a.costo,
                        total_costo = a.total_costo,
                        destino = a.destino,
                        horometro = a.horometro,
                        adicional = a.adicional,
                        horometro_ingresado = a.horometro_ingresado,
                        empresa = a.empresa,
                        Obra = a.Obra,
                        //2024-02-01: Función que define el tipo de llanta que se esta montando.
                        Operacion = FuntionLlantaEstadoMontaje(a.codigo, a.descripcion),
                        //2024-01-29: Utilizamos el operador condicional ternario para definir el indicando
                        //si ya fue insertada la información.
                        Estado = b == null ? "Pendiente" : "Insertada"
                    };
            return q.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception) 
        {
            return TemLlantasSalidasRegistrosExcepcion;
        }
    }

Comenzamos a indagar el porque sucedia esto y encontramos que los casos en los cuales la información ya habia sido insertada en la tabla pero aparecian como "Pendiente", tenian algo en particular, el campo b1.Equipo habia sido ingresado en minuscula ("mx-06") y el campo a.equipo habia sido ingresado en mayuscula ("MX-06"). Para validar que esta era la novedad, realizamos un UPDATE en la tabla donde se tomaba b1.Equipo y cambiamos de "mx-06" a "MX-06" para probar. Luego de hacer esto, el registro paso de "Pendiente" a "Insertada". Luego procedimos nuevamente a dejar el campo como estaba, osea en minuscula ("mx-06").
Debido a que eso pasa con muchos registros, no podemos hacerlo manualmente, cambiando uno a uno lo que estaba en minuscula por mayuscula, asi que encontramos un metodos que permite cambiar los campos tipo string de minuscula a mayuscula, el metodo es ToUpper(), el cual lo aplicamos al campo b1.Equipo asi:
Equipo = b1.Equipo.ToUpper(),

Con esto, pensamos que ya la validación funcionaría segun lo esperado, pero para sorpresa,
el campo de nuestro analisis, continuaba apareciendo como "Pendiente".
Agradecemos por favor sus indicaciones para lograr que esta parte del aplicativo funcione según esperamos.

primer problema, todo campo que sea cargado como los de ese tipo, deben ser cargados en su propia tabla, y luego el usuario tiene que seleccionarlo de alguna forma, para evitar errores en la descripcion...  mas alla de eso, tenes que hacer ToUpper a los dos, porque eso lo que hace es pasar a mayuscula todo el string, no solo una parte.. y para comparar, los dos tienen que ser mayuscula.. o usar un compare que agregue case insensitive ;)

Complementando el comentario anterior, podría ser String.Equals(Equipo, b1.Equipo, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

@javdromero gracias..

Agreadecemos los comentarios de gbianchi, con base en ellos, informamos que la solución fue ponerle el metodo ToUpper() a los dos campos que se comparaban asi:
[HttpGet("/Llantas/Salidas/Registros/Validados", Name = "GetLlantasSalidasRegistrosValidados")]
    public List<TemLlantasSalidasRegistros> GetLlantasSalidasRegistrosValidados(int Anho, int Mes, 
        string? Obra, string? Almacen) 
    {
        try
        {
            var t = GetLlantasSalidasAgregarObras(Anho, Mes);
            var q = from a in t
                    where
                        (
                            Obra == null
                            ||
                            Obra == ""
                            ||
                            Obra == a.Obra
                        )
                        &&
                        (
                            Almacen == null
                            ||
                            Almacen == ""
                            ||
                            Almacen == a.nom_bodega
                        )
                    // 2024-01-23: join con la tabla obtenida en GetLlantasHistoricosRegistros
                    join b1 in GetLlantasHistoricosRegistros(Anho, Mes) on new TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros
                    {
                        Fecha = a.fecha,
                        // 2024-04-23: Se utiliza el metodo ToUpper() para convertir todo el texto en mayuscula, para que sean iguales al compararse.
                        Equipo = a.equipo!.ToUpper(),
                        Salida = a.numero,
                        Bodega = a.bodega,
                        Cantidad = a.cantidad
                    }
                    equals new TemLlantasHistoricosRegistros
                    {
                        Fecha = b1.Fecha,
                        // 2024-04-23: Se utiliza el metodo ToUpper() para convertir todo el texto en mayuscula, para que sean iguales al compararse.
                        Equipo = b1.Equipo!.ToUpper(),
                        Salida = b1.Salida,
                        Bodega = b1.Bodega,
                        Cantidad = b1.Cantidad
                    }
                    into GrupoB
                    // 2024-01-23: esto lo hago para que que sean LEFT JOIN.
                    from b in GrupoB.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    orderby
                        a.Obra,
                        a.equipo,
                        a.fecha
                    select new TemLlantasSalidasRegistros
                    {
                        Registro = a.Registro,
                        equipo = a.equipo,
                        bodega = a.bodega,
                        nom_bodega = a.nom_bodega,
                        cod_familia = a.cod_familia,
                        familia = a.familia,
                        fecha = a.fecha,
                        codigo = a.codigo,
                        descripcion = a.descripcion,
                        tipo_salida = a.tipo_salida,
                        tipo = a.tipo,
                        numero = a.numero,
                        cantidad = a.cantidad,
                        costo = a.costo,
                        total_costo = a.total_costo,
                        destino = a.destino,
                        horometro = a.horometro,
                        adicional = a.adicional,
                        horometro_ingresado = a.horometro_ingresado,
                        empresa = a.empresa,
                        Obra = a.Obra,
                        //2024-02-01: Función que define el tipo de llanta que se esta montando.
                        Operacion = FuntionLlantaEstadoMontaje(a.codigo, a.descripcion),
                        //2024-01-29: Utilizamos el operador condicional ternario para definir el indicando
                        //si ya fue insertada la información.
                        Estado = b == null ? "Pendiente" : "Insertada"
                    };
            return q.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception) 
        {
            return TemLlantasSalidasRegistrosExcepcion;
        }
    }

De esta forma, nuestro aplicativo realizo la comparación correctamente.
